# My searchpage.php not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a search page for my current project. The scenario is simple, there is a form in index.php page the code is shown below:

```
 <form class="search-form" method="get" id="search_form" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">

    <fieldset>

        <input class="text" name="s" type="search" placeholder="Search for products I.E ( Fruit boxes )...">

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="">

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

so now I want when user enter his/her query and submits form, it should display a new page to show relevant results, no matter if posts or custom posts found or not ?

For that I am using "searchpage.php" and here is complete code for searchpage.php.

```
<?php $s=get_search_query(); $args = array( 's' =>$s) // The Query $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {  _e("<h2style='font-weight:bold;color:#000'>Search Results for:".get_query_var('s')</h2>");while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {$the_query->the_post();?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php}}else{?><h2 style='font-weight:bold;color:#000'>Nothing Found</h2><div class="alert alert-info"><p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p></div>
```

but i am not getting the results, while i search it goes back to index.php page again... have any one solution for this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the typical wordpress search form code:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
    <div>
            <label for="s" class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="" />

            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Not sure if wordpress requires a search.php template file, but normally this would be along the same lines as your archive.php file or index.php file

Comment: no, i tried this one too, but still not getting what i am hoping. any other idea will please ... ???? thanks for your time